# Flutter: child widget not rebuilding with parent widget using InheritedWidget

Tags: flutter, widget, rendering

I was just following along with this video on setting up a state management system in flutter using the "InheritedWidget" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFcGPS6cGrY&t=1307s and ran into this issue in my dummy "couponapp"

I have this widget "MyCouponsColumn" which holds children: List. This list is supposed to rerender onChange from my AppStateScope.of(context).myCoupons variable (Set), where the set is changed by temporary plus and minus buttons in the footer.

At the moment the buttons are changing the State but not rerendering the List, it does refresh after doing a manual hot reload (saving the code).

What am I missing?

***State Management System:***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(AppStateWidget(
    child: const MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme(
          background: Color(0xFF0D001A),
          primary: Color(0xFF896AE1),
          secondary: Color.fromARGB(255, 47, 34, 60),
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          surface: Color(0xFF896AE1),
          error: Color.fromARGB(255, 207, 95, 87),
          onPrimary: Color(0xFF0D001A),
          onSecondary: Colors.white,
          onSurface: Color(0xE6FFFFFF),
          onBackground: Colors.white,
          onError: Colors.white,
        ),
        fontFamily: GoogleFonts.lexend().fontFamily,
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

// App State Management
class AppState {
  // constructor
  AppState({
    this.myCoupons = const <String>{"Aral"}
  }) {
    print(this.myCoupons);
  }

  // State variables
  Set<String> myCoupons;

  // copy method
  AppState copyWith({
    Set<String>? myCoupons,
  }) {
    return AppState(
      myCoupons: myCoupons ?? this.myCoupons,
    );
  }
}

class AppStateScope extends InheritedWidget {
  AppStateScope(
    this.data, 
    {Key? key, required Widget child}
  ) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final AppState data;
  static AppState of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<AppStateScope>()!.data;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(AppStateScope oldWidget) {
    return data == oldWidget.data;
  }
}

// App State Widget - State Implementation
class AppStateWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  AppStateWidget({required this.child});

  final Widget child;

  static AppStateWidgetState of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.findAncestorStateOfType<AppStateWidgetState>()!;
  }
  @override
  AppStateWidgetState createState () => AppStateWidgetState();
}

class AppStateWidgetState extends State<AppStateWidget> {
  AppState _data = AppState();

  void addToCoupons(String name) {
    if (!_data.myCoupons.contains(name)) {
      setState((){
        final Set<String> newCoupons = Set<String>.from(_data.myCoupons);
        newCoupons.add(name);
        _data = _data.copyWith(myCoupons: newCoupons);
      });
    }
  }

  void removeFromCoupons(String name) {
    if (_data.myCoupons.contains(name)) {
      setState((){
        final Set<String> newCoupons = Set<String>.from(_data.myCoupons);
        newCoupons.remove(name);
        _data = _data.copyWith(myCoupons: newCoupons);
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppStateScope(_data, child: widget.child);
  }
}
```

Below this is the App Structure and inside of it:
***Footer Bar***

```
class FooterBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
          widthFactor: 1.6,
          child: Container(
            height: 110,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.elliptical(1000, 200),
                topRight: Radius.elliptical(1000, 200)
              ),
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            ),
            child: FractionallySizedBox(
              widthFactor: .6,
              child: Center(
                child: ButtonBar(
                  alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                      tooltip: "increase Coupons",
                      onPressed: () {
                        AppStateWidget.of(context).addToCoupons("Aral");
                        print(AppStateScope.of(context).myCoupons);
                      },
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                      tooltip: "increase Coupons",
                      onPressed: () {
                        AppStateWidget.of(context).removeFromCoupons("Aral");
                        print(AppStateScope.of(context).myCoupons);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***The CouponsColums***

```
class MyCouponsColumn extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Set<String> couponNames = AppStateScope.of(context).myCoupons;
    return Column(
      children: [
        for (String couponName in couponNames) MyCouponsCoupon(name: couponName)
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyCouponsCoupon extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCouponsCoupon({super.key, required String name});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
      child: Container(
        height: 170,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

*(Whole Pagecode)*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(AppStateWidget(
    child: const MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme(
          background: Color(0xFF0D001A),
          primary: Color(0xFF896AE1),
          secondary: Color.fromARGB(255, 47, 34, 60),
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          surface: Color(0xFF896AE1),
          error: Color.fromARGB(255, 207, 95, 87),
          onPrimary: Color(0xFF0D001A),
          onSecondary: Colors.white,
          onSurface: Color(0xE6FFFFFF),
          onBackground: Colors.white,
          onError: Colors.white,
        ),
        fontFamily: GoogleFonts.lexend().fontFamily,
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

// App State Management
class AppState {
  // constructor
  AppState({
    this.myCoupons = const <String>{"Aral"}
  }) {
    print(this.myCoupons);
  }

  // State variables
  Set<String> myCoupons;

  // copy method
  AppState copyWith({
    Set<String>? myCoupons,
  }) {
    return AppState(
      myCoupons: myCoupons ?? this.myCoupons,
    );
  }
}

class AppStateScope extends InheritedWidget {
  AppStateScope(
    this.data, 
    {Key? key, required Widget child}
  ) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final AppState data;
  static AppState of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<AppStateScope>()!.data;
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(AppStateScope oldWidget) {
    return data == oldWidget.data;
  }
}

// App State Widget - State Implementation
class AppStateWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  AppStateWidget({required this.child});

  final Widget child;

  static AppStateWidgetState of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.findAncestorStateOfType<AppStateWidgetState>()!;
  }
  @override
  AppStateWidgetState createState () => AppStateWidgetState();
}

class AppStateWidgetState extends State<AppStateWidget> {
  AppState _data = AppState();

  void addToCoupons(String name) {
    if (!_data.myCoupons.contains(name)) {
      setState((){
        final Set<String> newCoupons = Set<String>.from(_data.myCoupons);
        newCoupons.add(name);
        _data = _data.copyWith(myCoupons: newCoupons);
      });
    }
  }

  void removeFromCoupons(String name) {
    if (_data.myCoupons.contains(name)) {
      setState((){
        final Set<String> newCoupons = Set<String>.from(_data.myCoupons);
        newCoupons.remove(name);
        _data = _data.copyWith(myCoupons: newCoupons);
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppStateScope(_data, child: widget.child);
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(60.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary, 
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.elliptical(400, 20), bottomRight: Radius.elliptical(400, 20)),
          ),
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(bottom: 3),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
            ),
            child: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(0, 0, 0, 0),
              centerTitle: true,
              title: const Text("Couboost"),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: FractionallySizedBox(
        heightFactor: 1,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            // Body Content
            MyCouponsPageContent(),
            // Footer Bar
            FooterBar(),
          ],
        ),
      ), 
    );
  }
}

class FooterBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      left: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      right: 0,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: FractionallySizedBox(
          widthFactor: 1.6,
          child: Container(
            height: 110,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.elliptical(1000, 200),
                topRight: Radius.elliptical(1000, 200)
              ),
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            ),
            child: FractionallySizedBox(
              widthFactor: .6,
              child: Center(
                child: ButtonBar(
                  alignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                      tooltip: "increase Coupons",
                      onPressed: () {
                        AppStateWidget.of(context).addToCoupons("Aral");
                        print(AppStateScope.of(context).myCoupons);
                      },
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.remove),
                      tooltip: "increase Coupons",
                      onPressed: () {
                        AppStateWidget.of(context).removeFromCoupons("Aral");
                        print(AppStateScope.of(context).myCoupons);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCouponsPageContent extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children:[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: MyCouponsColumn(),
          ),
          // leave this as spacebuffer underneath the footerbar
          Container(
            height: 100,
            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCouponsColumn extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Set<String> couponNames = AppStateScope.of(context).myCoupons;
    return Column(
      children: [
        for (String couponName in couponNames) MyCouponsCoupon(name: couponName)
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyCouponsCoupon extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyCouponsCoupon({super.key, required String name});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
      child: Container(
        height: 170,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for taking a look and wish you all the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem:

The `InheritedWidget` isn't updating the `MyCouponsColumn` widget because there is a bug in the overridden `updateShouldNotify` method.

Currently, the code says that `updateShouldNotify` should be called when `data == oldWidget.data` which means it wouldn't notify `MyCouponsColumn` when the data changes.

### Solution:

Change this:

```dart
  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(AppStateScope oldWidget) {
    return data == oldWidget.data;
  }
```

to this:

```dart
  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(AppStateScope oldWidget) {
    return data != oldWidget.data; // Modify here
  }
```

Comment: That sounds correct, I knew it was something stupid, thanks a lot!